# How can I paginate within a while loop?

Tags: mysql, pagination, while-loop

I basically need to have take some videos information out of a database with a while loop and put them into a div. The only issue is that I need to put only 6 at a time in between a  and  tag and have it go to the next 6 and so forth. Here's my code:

```
$count = 0; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC";
$result_set = $database->query($sql);
while($videos = $database->fetch_array($result_set)) {
$count++;
    // i know this is horribly wrong...
if($count == 0 || (($count % 6)+1 == 1)) {
    echo '<div>';
}
    // i need 6 videos to go in between the <div> and </div> tags then go on to another 6
    echo "<a href=\"video/{$videos}\">{$videos['title']}</a>";


if($count == 0 || (($count % 6)+1 == 1)) {
    echo '<div>';
}           
}
```

Comment: Do you want to load all the videos from the db, and do the paging on the client side? or load 6 at a time from the db and do the paging server side?

Comment: I want to load all of them and do the paging on the client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an efficent way to do what you want:

```
$resultPerPage = 6;
$count = 0;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC";
$result_set = $database->query($sql);
$noPage = 1;

echo '<div id="page_1" class="pages">';
while($videos = $database->fetch_array($result_set)) {
    $count++;
    echo "<a href=\"video/{$videos}\">{$videos['title']}</a>";
    if($count == $resultPerPage) {
        echo '</div><div id="page_' . $noPage++ . '" class="pages">';
        $count=0;
    }       
}
echo '</div>';
```